# How to import Notes.app notes into Simplenotes.app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I now use Simplenote to take notes. On iOS I write directly in Simplenote.app and on OS X I write in nvAlt which syncs with Simplenote.

How can I export my hundreds of notes from my iOS Notes.app, where I used to write all my notes, into Simplenote? I'm open to any solution that doesn't involve manually going note-by-note.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

**[Answer from SimpleNote Agent](http://help.simplenoteapp.com/customer/portal/questions/3280-sync-with-note-in-iphone)**

Spoiler alert: Not unless you want to copy/paste. If you're a premium user of SimpleNote, you can email all of your Notes.app notes and import them that way.

The only other solution is if you can find a way to import a SQLite database into SimpleNote, in which case you would use the files located at:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy and paste each note! A real chore!!